# Force update QGraphicsItem regardless if it is visible in the QGraphicsView or not?

Tags: qt

I have some QGraphicsItems that their paint() needs to be executed regardless if they are outside the view or not, I can't change the boundingRect() since it is used for mouse selection.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way, enable the indirect painting flag in the QGraphicsView:
`setOptimizationFlag(QGraphicsView::IndirectPainting);`

this will enable using `QGraphicsView::drawItems()` where you can specify the items that are outside the viewport - or any items you want - and force paint it.